# Passing URLs with button touch in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, button

I'm building a basic app for my school and can't figure out how to change the URL to be presented based on the button pressed. I have four buttons and currently have them all linked to temporary URLs, but when I run my app, the webview appears blank and my NSLog returns null for the URL. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

TWViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TWViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)gradesPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)facPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newsPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sportsPressed:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;

@end
```

TWViewController.m:

```
#import "TWViewController.h"
#import "TWWebViewController.h"

@interface TWViewController ()

@end

@implementation TWViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)gradesPressed:(id)sender{
    TWWebViewController *webView = [[TWWebViewController alloc] init];
    webView.website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
}

- (IBAction)facPressed:(id)sender {
    TWWebViewController *webView = [[TWWebViewController alloc] init];
    webView.website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yahoo.com"];
}

- (IBAction)newsPressed:(id)sender {
    TWWebViewController *webView = [[TWWebViewController alloc] init];
    webView.website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"];
}

- (IBAction)sportsPressed:(id)sender {
    TWWebViewController *webView = [[TWWebViewController alloc] init];
    webView.website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
//    
//    TWWebViewController *wbc = (TWWebViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
//}

@end
```

TWWebViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TWWebViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *webView;
    NSString *website;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *website;
@end
```

TWWebViewController.m:

```
#import "TWWebViewController.h"
#import "TWWebViewController.h"

@interface TWWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation TWWebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.website];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    NSLog(@"%@", website);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I'm fairly new to iOS Development, so I'm not quite sure if I'm even on the right track. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push your controller after initializing it: Also, your NSString is not an NSURL object so do this also in your TWWebViewController: `NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.website]];`

TWWebViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:self.website]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

TWViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)sportsPressed:(id)sender 
{
    TWWebViewController *webView = [self.storyboard 
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
    webView.website = @"http://apple.com";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
}
```

Also don't forget to do this in your storyboard file:

[image]

Comment: All that pops up in the debugger console is `(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x18408a, 0x0156c8b9 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1` and breakpoint 1.1 highlights `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TWAppDelegate class]));` sorry that didn't help much. I don't have a viewDidAppear function in TWViewController either

Comment: You must be doing something else.

Comment: Can you explain how to find the error and maybe that will help? I've been pouring through debug data for hours...

Comment: Set a breakpoint every other line where you have non stock Apple code and step through each line, when it 'crashes' there is basically your problem

Comment: I put one on every other line of code that I added per your suggestion and everything worked fine. The only problem I have is when I press the back button at the top left of the app it goes to a black screen that says the name of my app where "back" used to be and when I click again the app crashes. I can't find the problem in my code... should I just ask a new question?

Comment: Any way for you to post a sample barebones app .zip on dropbox? Feel free to omit anything personal in app that gives away your app idea, as long as the issue is recreatable that is fine. I'll be glad to help

Comment: Not sure if I did this right, don't know what barebones means... I just took the personal info out of it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc0xqy2lx8r93lc/SampleApp.zip

Comment: Here is the fixed project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22522445/SampleApp-Fixed.zip

Comment: Thanks a billion man. Is there any way I can get help from you if I need anything else?

Comment: Can you upvote my answer? And yeah, post a question on here and i most likely will see it in the iOS section

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, when I get it, I will. Hey can you explain why you removed the segues on the storyboard?

Comment: They werent necessary since we did a different way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: When I get the rep I will